# Getting an array from one property of an associative array best practice

Tags: php, array

I have an array of objects eg.

[
   array(
    'id' => 1,
   'name' => "simon"
),
...
]

and I need to get an array of IDs eg.
[1,2,3,4,5];

Currently I'm doing this:

```
    $entities = $this->works_order_model->get_assigned_entities($id);

    $employee_ids = array();

    foreach ($entities as $entity) {
        array_push($employee_ids, $entity->id);
    }
```

Is there a best practice way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think array_map is what you are looking for:

```
php > $aa = array (array ("id" => 1, "name" => 'what'), array('id' => 2));
php > function id($i) { return $i['id'];};
php > print_r(array_map ('id', $aa));
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is the function id() necessary? 
I don't see it being used.

Comment: It is used as the first argument to array_map (the first argument is a string that is the name of a function to use).